# Using iloc to replace a column when identical names exist

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

Suppose I have the following DataFrame with some identical column names

```
test = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3, np.nan, np.nan],
                     [1, 2, 3,      4,      5],
                     [1, 2, 3, np.nan, np.nan],
                     [1, 2, 3,      4, np.nan]],
                    columns=['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Three', 'Three'])
```

and I want to fill the `NaNs` in the fourth column. I would expect to be able to use `iloc` like

```
test.iloc[:, 3] = test.iloc[:, 3].fillna('F')
```

but this gives

```
In [121]: test
Out[121]:
   One  Two Three Three Three
0    1    2     F     F     F
1    1    2     4     4     4
2    1    2     F     F     F
3    1    2     4     4     4
```

So it changes based on the column name and not the position. I could do it very naïvely like the following.

```
c = test.columns
test.columns = range(len(test.columns))
test.iloc[:, 3] = test.iloc[:, 3].fillna('F')
test.columns = c
```

which gives the correct result

```
In [142]: test
Out[142]:
   One  Two  Three  Three  Three
0    1    2      3      F    NaN
1    1    2      3      4    5.0
2    1    2      3      F    NaN
3    1    2      3      4    NaN
```

but seems a bit inefficient considering the simple task.

My question is then twofold.

- Would there be a more straightforward method?
- Why doesn't the first one work? (why does `iloc` still resort to names when replacing columns?)

Comment: Some quick thoughts:  (1) seems like a bug to me and in playing around with this I noticed that the duplicated column names also messes up `stack()`, (2) it seems strange to me that pandas would even allow duplicated column names (you can't do this with dictionary keys, for example), (3) from a user point of view, I would never want to have duplicate column names so I'd recommend simply not having duplicate column names in the first place!  ;-)

Comment: But for this very *very* specific application I actually need the duplicate column names -- it's research code. :-) Duplicate names should somehow be possible if I only want to use numerical indexing. It also seems to mess up `melt` as each cell is duplicated as many times as there are columns with the name.

Comment: Sure, but if you are using numerical indexing, then it doesn't matter what the names/labels are anyway, so why no avoid having duplicate names  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your second question as to why the first technique doesn't work could be because of the way Pandas treats duplicate columns. While the constructor for a `DataFrame` doesn't have any setting for that, the `read_csv`[documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) has a parameter `mangle_dupe_cols` whose default value is True. The documentation says that passing in False could lead to data overwrite. I suspect Pandas treats duplicate columns in a questionable way.

Answer (score 0):

'`iloc` is indexing a dataframe object and `fillna` is looking for a series, hence it won't let you apply the `fillna`.

More straightforward is to just replace the values that are NaN after indexing them:

```
test.iloc[:,1][test.iloc[:,1].isnull()] = 'F'
```

Or alternatively (and closer to your original code), actually select the column:

```
test.iloc[:, 3]['Three] = test.iloc[:, 3]['Three'].fillna('F')
```

Comment: Neither of these options works for me. What are you trying to do here? Also, test.iloc[:,3] does return a series: `test_s = test.iloc[:,3]` and `print(type(test_s))` returns `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`.

Comment: @jack6e What happens when you use the first method? works just fine for me

Comment: Running `test.iloc[:,1][test.iloc[:,1].isnull()] = 'F'` produces no changes - probably because it is using `[:,1]` instead of `[:,3]`. Using `[:,3]` results in all 'Three' columns being converted to `'NaN 4.0 NaN 4.0'` values. Your second proposed method has a typo (`['Three]` is missing a '), but correcting that and running it produces "TypeError: an integer is required."